# How to sort arrays inside a list using python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

How can i sort these arrays inside the list in alphabetic order of names using python ?

```
[(1, 'Robert Downey', 40, '+919876543210', 15000), (2, 'Chris Evans', 35, '+919876543201', 30000), (3, 'Paul Rudd', 45, '+919876543021', 25000), (4, 'Tom Hardy', 39, '+919876540321', 40000), (5, 'Christian Bale', 30, '+919876504321', 10000), (6, 'Thomas shelby', 50, '+91234567890', 90000), (7, 'Tony Stark', 45, '+91087654296', 100000)]
```

i tried sort() function in python but it sorted on the basis of id number(first value in each array)

Comment: Do you want to sort by names?

Comment: `sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[1])`